# css animation only working in safari

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm pretty new at web development, but I'm trying to animate my logo (represented in the codepen by the blue rectangle) for my portfolio website. There are actually two animations. 1. fadein: the logo fades in from the top 2. shrink: (after a 3 second delay) the logo moves from the middle of the page to the top left corner and shrinks a bit.

If you open the pen in safari you'll see it working, but if you open it in chrome or firefox (given that you change the -webkit-) it sort of blends the two animations into one.

Any ideas to why this might happen en how to fix it?

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjobKd#0)

```
    div
{
  height: 150px;
  width: 170px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: blue;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s, 2s;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadein, shrink;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0, 3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein
{
    0% {opacity: 0; top: 30%; left: 50%; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -85px;}
    100% {opacity: 1; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -85px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes shrink
{
    0% {top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -85px;}
    100% {top: 50px; left: 20px; margin: 0; width: 84px; height: 74px;}    
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your animation delay. I'm not sure if it's bugged or as specification, but it doesn't work if you don't pass a unit, not even for zero.

```
-webkit-animation-delay: 0s, 3s;
```

That is, using `0s` instead of `0`.

Comment: That does indeed seem to solve my problem, thanks! Strange that safari doesn't care about the unit.